# How I want to delete array values other than integers

Tags: python-3.6

```
messy_list = ["a", 2, 3, 1, False, [1, 2, 3]]
for items in messy_list:
    if items.isdigit() == 0:
        messy_list.remove(items)
```

Please help me to do so?

Comment: but [1,2,3] must be kept as a list????

Comment: I am no pro in python, but what about creating a string out of every element in your table, then use a regex on it to remove non integer part, and then rebuild the table out of it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (not in-place):

```
lst = [item for item in messy_list if isinstance(item, int) and not isinstance(item, bool)]
```